# Obscure Javascript difference between IE / Firefox / Opera

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, opera

Within a "cloaked" site, using `obj.innerHTML = something` to change the contents of a div seems to screw up the div's position in Firefox and Opera.

Best way to understand the problem is by seeing the code in action. Go to http://www.guggs.net/index_redirected.htm in IE, Firefox or Opera and everything looks as it should.

Hit one of the links in IE and everything is still fine, but in Firefox the page gets misaligned and there's no way of getting it back into shape.

Hit one of the links in Opera and the misalignment happens but if you then hit another link the page is OK again and remains so however many links you hit.

If however you go straight to http://www.sensetech.me.uk/guggs which is the page behind the "cloak" it's all fine whichever browser you use and however many links you hit.

Help !

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host 'guggs.net.mysql' (1) in /home/sensete/public_html/guggs/inc/db_connect.php on line 18
Error connecting to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

1. validate
2. I see no difference in F 3.6.10 on Mac
3. fix at least this:

Warning: Expected end of value but found ','.  Error in parsing value for 'padding'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: /guggs/css.css
Line: 39

```
td {
    font: 9pt verdana;
    color:#665544;
    padding: 0px, 0px, 0px, 5px;
}
```

Comment: @Neil: the fix for the problem above is to remove the commas in the `padding` rule. It should be `padding: 0 0 0 5px;` (yes, you can omit the units on the zeros)

Comment: No, Matt, that makes no difference but thanks for pointing it out. And the SQL error is a red herring. Once this formatting issue is corrected I'll get the database access fixed too.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

Nothing do with the Javascript ! FireFox and Opera were tripping due to earlier PHP code intended to prevent users coming in through anything other than the index page. Works OK when the site isn't cloaked so I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but for the moment I've removed the code, which isn't anything like vital.

Thanks for your time, people !